# Will http3 support UDP from javascript within browser

Tags: javascript, udp, webrtc, quic, http3

As browsers and servers implement Http3, a lot of TCP communication will move over to UDP (QUIC).

However, it is not clear to me whether the UDP based communication primitives will be available from within the browser itself. Meaning, like one can do Ajax requests today through javascript, will browser javascript support UDP requests? Or better, large messages over UDP reliably (with necessary encryption built on top of UDP via the wrapping QUIC of course)?

This will simplify peer to peer browser communication and open up many innovative applications. Today these need to take the cumbersome STUN/TURN and WebRTC  (which also uses UDP underneath) routes.

But then direct UDP has other issues, especially security concerns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... like one can do Ajax requests today through javascript, will browser javascript support UDP requests?

Ajax is still HTTP and not plain TCP. Ajax will continue to work and will transparently use HTTP/3 if available.

> ... Or better, large messages over UDP reliably (with necessary encryption built on top of UDP via the wrapping QUIC of course)?

Similar, large messages which until now used HTTP/1 or HTTP/2 over TCP will now transparently use HTTP/3 over UDP.

> This will simplify peer to peer browser communication and open up many innovative applications. Today these need to take the cumbersome STUN/TURN and WebRTC (which also uses UDP underneath) routes.

No, it will not help with this. HTTP/3 will not provide plain UDP connections  the same as HTTP/1 and HTTP/2 did not provide plain TCP connections.